# How to write Plist file in cocos2d to transfer data from one level to another level

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, plist, box2d-iphone

```
-(void)writeToTopScorePlist<br>
{
   <br>
   NSError *error;<br>
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1<br>
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2<br>
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TopScore.plist"]; //3<br>
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];<br>
   if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4<br>
   {<br>
          NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TopScore" ofType:@"plist"]; //5<br>
          [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6<br>
   }<br>
   NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path ];<br>
    [data setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.MyTopScore] forKey:@"TopScore"];<br>
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];<br>
    [data release] ;<br>
   }
```

Comment: what is <br> in code ? Obj.C or HTML..lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults:

```
// Code used to save your highscore in the preference
int topscore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:topscore] forKey:@"topscore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


// Code used to get your saved value from the prefs.
topScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"topscore"] intValue ];
```

Comment: Please tell me one more thing if i want to move one stage body to another stage than what i do with plist file. Please suggest

Comment: just save status of body, like position rotation and load again in new level.